# Let $\ell^2$ be the set of sequences $\{a_n\}$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_n^2$ is convergent.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, metric-spaces

Also let $c_0$ be the set of sequences that converge to $0$ and let $\ell^\infty$ be the set of all bounded sequences.

It is easy to see that $\ell^2$ is a subset of $c_0$ which is a subset of $\ell^\infty$

The $c_0$ metric is $\sup \{|a_n-b_n|\}$.

Anyways, is $\ell^2$ closed in $c_0$?(meaning that if $\{a^{(k)}\}$ is a sequence of points in $\ell^2$ and "$a$" is an element of $c_0$ (sequence that converges to $0$) such that $a^{(k)}$ converges to a with respect to the $c_0$ metric, must we have "$a$" as an element of $l^2$?

If so, would $c_0$ be open in $\ell^\infty$?

Comment: I recommend you to learn how to use TeX math formulas.

Comment: For the last question, the only open subspace is the space, since any ball around $0$ contains a basis.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you consider $\ell^2$ with the $c_0$ metric, then $\ell^2$ is not closed in $c_0$. In fact, it is dense in $c_0$, because the set
   $$
   c_{00} = \{(x_n) : \exists N \in \mathbb{N} \text{ such that } x_n = 0 \quad\forall n\geq N\}
   $$
   is a subset of $\ell^2$, which is dense in $c_0$.

However, note that $\ell^2$ with the euclidean distance  is complete.

2. $c_0$ is not open in $\ell^{\infty}$. In fact, one can show that if a subspace of a normed linear space contains a non-empty open set, then the subspace must be the whole space. Ergo, if $c_0$ were open, then it would be all of $\ell^{\infty}$, which it is not.

Comment: I cannot wrap my head around what it means for it to be dense or compact. We have never used those terms, so maybe an answer without those would help. Perhaps an example where we don't use compact and sense would help.

Comment: Take the sequence $(a_n) \in \ell^2$ given by $$a_n(k) = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} &: 1\leq k\leq n \\ 0 &: k > n \end{cases} $$ and prove that it converges to $a := (1/\sqrt{n})_{n\geq 1}$ in $c_0$. Now $a_n \in \ell^2$ for all $n$, but $a\notin \ell^2$, so $\ell^2$ is not closed.

Comment: so it safe to say that since the sequence 1/rootk converges to 0 but the sum of the roots does not converge, then it's not closed?